# Working with Access Control in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, private, getter

I want to get device ID in at all classes level in swift which will be included as parameter every time async call made.And I really don't get clearly about Apple Access Control.So,I really need help

So,How to make saving device id at start point and them accessible to all classes for async request?

In app,didFinishLaunchingWithOptions,I will add the following code
let say keychain is the library where i store value

```
if keychain.get("deviceID") == nil{
     keychain.set(UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor!.UUIDString,forKey : ”deviceID”)
     //some private var deviceID = keychain.get(“deviceID”)
}
else{
    some private var deviceID = keychain.get(“deviceID”)
}
```

And I want to access that private var at everywhere in the UIViewController class.

```
class ViewController : UIViewController {
     let deviceID = //some private var with getter?
}
```

Is there any idea that i can do in swift?using Apple Access Control?

And that problem is connected to that question : [Getting Device ID is not unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35520124/getting-device-id-is-not-unique?noredirect=1#comment58730671_35520124)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define your deviceID as static and you will be able to access it everywhere

after your code to initiate the keychain, set it as a static at some class

```
class DeviceArg {
 static var deviceId = keychain.get(“deviceID”)
}


// some other place in the code
let check = DeviceArg.deviceId //get deviceId
```

Comment: What about setting it value?

Comment: DeviceArg.deviceId = "some new value"

Comment: let check = DeviceArg.deviceId return "",Any help?

Answer (score -1):

Check My Code :-

```
var mytoken1: String = deviceToken.description.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("<", withString: "")
var mytoken2: String = mytoken1.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(">", withString: "")
mytoken2 = mytoken2.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(mytoken2, forKey: "DEVICE_TOKEN")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```